# ZMQ drop old messages

Tags: python, zeromq, pyzmq

I am trying to create a real life system where an action needs to be performed by the subscriber on real-time data provided by the publisher. Sometimes the PUB and SUB get out of sync(by up to 10 seconds) because they are performing some operations and I always need the latest data from the publisher other wise the actions performed by the subscriber will be way off.

I am trying to use a SUB/PUB approach and I am trying set a HWM limit but it does not seems to work.
I have tried the disconnect approach but it adds an additional one second lag into the system and 90% of the time my system is working in real time so by using disconnect the whole system collapses.

Subscriber(I am trying to model the actual system through time.sleep()):

```
import time
import zmq
import random

context = zmq.Context()
consumer_receiver = context.socket(zmq.SUB)

consumer_receiver.set_hwm(0)
consumer_receiver.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5555")

consumer_receiver.subscribe(b'')


while 1:
    d=random.randint(0,10)

    work = consumer_receiver.recv_pyobj()
    # consumer_receiver.disconnect()
    print(work,"  :",d)
    time.sleep(d)
```

Publisher:

```
import time
import zmq

context = zmq.Context()
zmq_socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
zmq_socket.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:5555")

for x in range(1000):

    # zmq_socket.send_string("", zmq.SNDMORE)
    zmq_socket.send_pyobj(x,zmq.NOBLOCK)
    time.sleep(1)
    print(x)
```

Comment: `zmq.CONFLATE` keeps the last message only, in other words, you will destroy the queue. So there is another option which sets a limit on the queue using `zmq.RCVBUF` on subscriber side and `zmq.SNDBUF` option on publisher side. [Check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53360536/3702377), hope help you up.

Comment: Thanks but I am working with a feedback system and I really only need the latest data I have the luxury to ignore some data (i need speed over accuracy) so Conflate is really what i needed. Thanks for the info though it might help out on another project that i am working on

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK my savior is [CONFLATE](http://api.zeromq.org/4-0:zmq-setsockopt). Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25940962/zeromq-i-want-publish-subscribe-to-drop-older-messages-in-favor-of-newer-ones) post the problem seems to be solved

```
import time
import zmq
import random

context = zmq.Context()
consumer_receiver = context.socket(zmq.SUB)    

consumer_receiver.setsockopt(zmq.CONFLATE, 1)

consumer_receiver.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5555") 
consumer_receiver.subscribe(b'')


while 1:
    d=random.randint(1,10)

    work = consumer_receiver.recv_pyobj()

    print(work,"  :",d)

    time.sleep(d)
```